# Why failing to tlmgr update TeXLive in Debian 8.5?

Tags: debian, latex, software-updates

I run unsuccessfully the following and get strange output 404 first and then unknown hash from `wget`:

```
root@masi:/home/masi/Documents/# tlmgr update --self
```

output

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
TLDownload::get_file: response error: 404 File 'texlive.tlpdb.xz' not found (for ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/TeX/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb.xz)
TLUtils::download_file: persistent connection ok, but download failed: ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/TeX/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb.xz
TLUtils::download_file: retrying with wget.
TLUtils::download_file: retry with wget succeeded: ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/TeX/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb.xz
Unknown directive ...containerchecksum c59200574a316416a23695c258edf3a32531fbda43ccdc09360ee105c3f07f9fb77df17c4ba4c2ea4f3a5ea6667e064b51e3d8c2fe6c984ba3e71b4e32716955... , please fix it! at /usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 210, <$retfh> line 5579.
```

Problem has occurred 27th Nov and 30th Dec 2016.

### Confusion about TeXLive version

I do the following which indicates TeXLive 2015 as root:

```
root@masi:/home/masi# tex -version
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015/dev/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.1dev
Copyright 2014 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
```

I run as `masi`

```
masi@masi:~$ tex --version
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016)
kpathsea version 6.2.2
Copyright 2016 D.E. Knuth.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the TeX source.
Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
```

I run `xelatex` on any document which indicates *TeXLive 2016* as `masi`

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3experimental/l3str/l3flag.sty)
```

Also as `masi`

```
command -v tlmgr
/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr
```

Also as `masi`

```
command -v tex
/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/tex
```

TeXLive: 2016, 2015
OS: Debian 8.5
Instructions: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55459/13173)

Comment: I had the same problem when I tried to use `tlmgr` with texlive 2015. When I looked around, they told me that the repositories that `tlmgr` tried to use are not available anymore, they gave me this command to change the default repository `tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2015/tlnet-final`. Since you are with texlive 2016, try to change the repositories to this for example `tlmgr option repository http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet` (found it [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313271/change-tex-live-main-repository))

Comment: Sorry for this question, but are you sure you are using texlive 2016, can you give the first line of the output  `tex --version` here in comments.

Comment: If you wanna just tlmgr, use this command `tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2015/tlnet-final`. If you wanna update to texlive 2016, you can see here [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)

Comment: May be you installed the two versions (somehow), but tlmgr is using the 2015 version.

Comment: Ah okay. I guess that the 2015 version was installed before, and when you type `tlmgr` (or `tex`) he is using tlmgr of the 2015 version. You can manually search for the `tlmgr` of the 2016 version by going to the folder where you installed texlive 2016, and execute this command `find . -name "tlmgr"`. Then you can use it by typing it's absolute path.

Comment: This is a dirty work around, and I don't really like it. What I really advice you to do is one of these two : remove what you installed, and install the texlive with `apt` (it's the cleanest and the easiest way to proceed, but you might not have the last version of `texlive`) ; the second proposal is to install a clean version of 2016 by following this tutorial [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)

Comment: What is the output of the command `apt-cache show`. If something is showed, it means that there is texlive in the official repositories, and that you can install it easily with `apt-get`.

Comment: ah, looooool, I know what's wrong. give me the command that told you to put in .bashrc in the tutorial you followed. A command that contains the word "PATH"

Comment: yes, you can use -p, or the `export` word before the PATH.

Comment: okay, enjoy LaTeX. Please change your question by removing the part "testing sidahmed proposal". This way, the other users can bennefit of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem: different PATH in `masi` and `root` so use `su -p` not to change the PATH when going to `root`. 
My proposal for workaround

```
su -p
tlmgr update --self
```

Output

```
tlmgr: package repository http://mirror.datacenter.by/pub/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2016/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr: no self-updates for tlmgr available.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

When you go root, use this `sudo -sE` or this `su -p` to preserve the environment variables in the current session.

## Explanation

Your system is using different `texlive` versions for different users, and that's because of the environment variable `PATH`.

When you are in terminal, and you type a command, the shell will look for the corresponding program in your `PATH` directories. But the thing is, there is different priority when the shell looks for a program in the `PATH`. For example, I have this `PATH` variable :

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/snap/bin
```

If I type `date` in the terminal, the shell will look for the program `date` in the directory `/usr/local/sbin`, if not found he will look in `/usr/local/bin`, if not found ... until he look into all the directories.

When you installed manually `texlive` 2016, at some point you used the instruction `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/:$PATH`. This way, you made your shell look first in the directory `/usr/local/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux/` if you type any command. The only problem is that the instruction below wasn't applied to all the users, so when you go root, your `PATH` variable will be restored to its original content.

That's why when executing the same command from `masi` and `root` gives you two different programs. The solution is to use `sudo -sE` or `su -p` to preserve the environment variables of the previous user.

Comment: I awarded you the bounty because you participated in the discussion.