# Updating TLMGR on Linux Mint (Debian)

Tags: debian, linux-mint, latex

I want to install a Latex package, so I run:

```
(env) mvh:~$ tlmgr install verbatim
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2019)
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
Please see https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

I go to [the website linked above](https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html) and download and run `update-tlmgr-latest.sh`, and I get:

```
(env) mvh:Downloads$ bash update-tlmgr-latest.sh 
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater  100%  
./runme.sh: Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT.
./runme.sh: (no tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb and/or tlpkg/tlpobj/.)
./runme.sh: Please set your PATH as needed, otherwise it's hopeless.
```

This despite the fact that in my `./bashrc`, I have:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/share/texlive/
```

And indeed, if I check where `texlive` is, using `whereis`, I get exactly the directory above.  Interestingly, the instructions linked above seem to want there to be a folder with a year in its name in the `texlive` install.

> Unix
>
> 1. Find the parent directory of the current installation; it's 
>      /usr/local/texlive by default.
> 2. Copy the whole directory 2018 to 2019, preserving symbolic links; for example:
>      cp -a 2018 2019
>      If you don't understand this, stop here and do a regular installation.

However, I appear to have no such folders ...

```
(env) mvh:texlive$ whereis texlive
texlive: /usr/share/texlive
(env) mvh:texlive$ cd
(env) mvh:~$ whereis texlive
texlive: /usr/share/texlive
(env) mvh:~$ cd /usr/share/texlive
(env) mvh:texlive$ ls
debian  doc.html  index.html  LICENSE.CTAN  LICENSE.TL  README  readme-html.dir  readme-txt.dir  README.usergroups  release-texlive.txt  texmf-dist  tlpkg
```

I am running Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon, and I installed `texlive-full` using `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`.  So far, I have tried, to no avail: ([this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/333994/181623)), ([this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/333996/181623)), the instructions under 2. ([here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/pkginstall.html)), most of ([this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55459/150028)), and ([this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/504928/150028)).  I also tried [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429718/150028), to no avail:

```
(env) root:texlive# sudo tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2017/tlnet-final
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: setting default package repository to ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2017/tlnet-final
(env) root:texlive# tlmgr update --self
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
/usr/bin/tlmgr: open tlpdb(ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2017/tlnet-final/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb) failed:  at /usr/share/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm line 362.
```

How can I update `tlmgr` so I can install packages (and do my homework)?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you need to install `verbatim`? It’s part of the LaTeX `tools` package, which is included in the basic installation of LaTeX. In Linux Mint, it’s part of the `texlive-latex-base` package (`sudo apt install texlive-latex-base` if you don’t have it already). `verbatim` hasn’t changed since 2003.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - I just used verbatim as an example.  I really need code and ttquot.  For now I am temporarily just using sty Giles but I would prefer to actually have a working tlmgr installation so I can easily install these packages globally, and also to handle this situation in the future without needing to rely on apt cache searching for something that happens to include what I want ... thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from a Debian-packages TeX Live installation, I would recommend always running `tlmgr` as yourself, not root:

```
tlmgr init-usertree
```

will set your user tree up, and then

```
tlmgr option repository ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/2017/tlnet-final
```

should be used to point `tlmgr` at the repository matching your installation (2017 for Linux Mint, 2018 for Debian 10, etc.).

Once that’s done,

```
tlmgr install ...
```

will install the package you’re after, assuming it’s available (which isn’t the case for either [`code`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/code) or `ttquot`).